# Retaining around 1KB of data across different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, viewstate

Using Javascript / Jquery (1.7) / Ajax , is it possible to retain around 1kb of data across 2 different pages on the same domain?

For example, a user will enter information into a textbox, and navigate away from this page onto a specific different page.

Is it then possible to `alert` the user with the textbox information from the previous page?

Comment: You could store the information in a cookie, when the textbox value is changed (`onchange` event). Then on page load, you could check this cookie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store that amount of information:

- In [cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) (up to 4K)
- In [local/session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) ([limits](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/) start from 2.5MB)
- In the [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers) (e.g. via a query string or fragment id) (up to 2,083 characters in IE)